# Standard FileField as dropzone upload area in Django form

Tags: python, django, dropzone.js

How can I set `myfile` form field as Dropzone.js upload area?

forms.py

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    myfile = FileField()
```

views.py

```
class ExampleView(FormView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = TestForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print form.cleaned_data['title']
        print form.cleaned_data['file']
        return super(ExampleView, self).form_valid(form)
```

test.html

```
<form method="post" action="/test-form/">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="id_title">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just checked the dropzone website, and there are a few different ways. 
One would be by configuring the `paramName` option: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-paramName

But it looks like you could just add the file field, e.g., `<input type="file" name="myfile" />`

You'll need to add `class="dropzone"` to the form.